# crystal reports giving Database logon failed or asking for credentials

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

i have tried almost everything I could. I have a web app in ASP.net with c#. I am fetching data from the database tables and adding it to dataset. Then I set this dataset as the source to the report. My code is as following.

```
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["familyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select uid, member_name, gender, dob from family where uid='"+uid+"'", con);
            DataSet1 myds = new DataSet1();
            sda.Fill(myds, "family");


            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select id from birth_certificates where p_id='"+uid+"'", con);
            sda1.Fill(myds, "birth_certificates");

            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("birth_certi_report.rpt"));
            rpt.Refresh();
            rpt.SetDataSource(myds);
            rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("","",@".\sqlexpress","project2");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I am using integrated security so I left username and password blank. Please help.

[image: Asking for Credentials]

Please Note that the above code is written inside a DropDown_selectedIndexChanged() event. I tried adding it to the page_load but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about authentication ,then do it this way.Create an instance of your crystal report and set its data source.Thats all you need to do and it works.
*Make sure the crystal report is within your solution.

```
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["familyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
      // the magic
        birth_certi_report myreport = new birth_certi_report();
        DataSet1 myds = new DataSet1();
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select id from birth_certificates where p_id='"+uid+"'", con);
        sda1.Fill(myds, "birth_certificates");
        myreport.SetDataSource(myds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent all day on it and you helped me.

Comment: Can you please be kind enough to explain why it did not work with ReportDocument?

Comment: When using report document you have to perform some extra steps in the page load to suppress the login information.Take a look at an excellent post here  http://blackmarketserver.com/blog/2010/07/19/suppress-login-prompt-crystal-reports-and-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

birth_certi_report myreport = new birth_certi_report();

in this line you have mentioned that birth_certi_report is crystal report. my crystal report name is applicationreport but it shows an error.

Dim myreport As New appilcationreport

error is TYPE IS NOT DEFINED