# Crystal Report Viewer - Logon prompt

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I have some Crystal Reports off a customer which I need to link to an ASP.NET application we are creating. I have the following code:

```
 LINQDataContext dc = new LINQDataContext();
        Order o = dc.Orders.Where(a => a.ID == long.Parse(Request.QueryString["OrderID"])).Single();
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder bld = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(dc.Connection.ConnectionString);
        CrystalReportSource src = new CrystalReportSource();
        src.ID = "test";
        ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = bld.DataSource;
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = bld.InitialCatalog;
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = bld.UserID;
        myConnectionInfo.Password = bld.Password;

        src.Report.FileName = o.SalesPersonObject.GetType().GetProperty(Request.QueryString["DeliveryNoteType"]).GetValue(o.SalesPersonObject, null).ToString();


        ParameterDiscreteValue param = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        param.Value = long.Parse(Request.QueryString["OrderID"]); 
        src.ReportDocument.ParameterFields[0].CurrentValues.Add(param); 

        CrystalReportViewer vw = new CrystalReportViewer();
        src.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(bld.UserID, bld.Password);
        vw.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
        vw.AutoDataBind = true;
        vw.Height = 1268;
        vw.Width = 1000;
        vw.HasPrintButton = true;
        vw.PrintMode = PrintMode.Pdf;
        vw.ReportSource = src;
        //vw.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = false;
        vw.HasToggleParameterPanelButton = false;
        vw.HasCrystalLogo = false;
        vw.RefreshReport();
        plcReport.Controls.Add(vw);
```

However, even though I'm setting the username/password using the SetDatabaseLogon method, I'm still getting a prompt to enter the database login details, or more specifically to enter the password. I've tried using vw.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = true, but that gives me a database login issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I helped another **SO user** who was facing a similar problem .I hope you will be able to get something valuable.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412116/crystal-reports-giving-database-logon-failed-or-asking-for-credentials/14413395#14413395)

Answer (score 0):

For your connection, use the OLE driver; don't use the native SQL driver.  Not sure if that's your current issue, but my experience has been that if I use the native driver it works okay in development, but then always prompts for a login in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the the following code:

```
using CrystalDecisions;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;


public partial class ClientsByOpeningDate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
             rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("ClientsByOpenDate.rpt"));
             rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("myUserLogin", "mypassword", @"Server", "Database");
             CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        }
    }
}
```